# Is there any way to convert joomla 2.5 passwords(md5+salt) for a joomla 3.x site to use?

Tags: php, joomla, passwords, data-migration, user-data

Im making a new joomla 3.x site and i'd like to get all the users from an old 2.5 site but their passwords aren't working on the new site because of joomla 3's different password encryption method.
Is there any way to convert the old passwords to work like the new ones? Or is there any option for joomla 3 to use the old password encryption?
Or I just have to generate a new pass for everbody and email it to them?

Comment: Try asking your question over at [Joomla Stack Exchange](http://joomla.stackexchange.com) ;)

Comment: 3.x seems to handle md5, https://github.com/joomla/joomla-cms/blob/staging/libraries/joomla/crypt/password/simple.php look at `verify($password, $hash)`

Comment: right, sorry 
im moving this to Joomla Stack Exchange

Comment: Thanks Bang it really does, the problem in my case was with not setting a registered group for the test records I used, but now its works!